# Show text in a label after refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh

When I update a value in database, it doesn't show anymore in my drop-down-list. I update my page to not show this value in my drop-down-list anymore. Now I refresh the page automatically after removing this item so you can't choose that item again but I want to show in a label that "This value was removed!".
But it won't appear after the page is refresh.

```
    protected void btnBevRekeningVerwijderen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        B.RekeningVerwijderen(Convert.ToInt32(ddlRekeningVerwijderen.SelectedValue));
        Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);

        lblRekeningMakenInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblRekeningMakenInfo.Text = "The value is removed!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label won't show if you refresh the page (could be simpler if it didn't), however now you can use Session or Cookie:

```
if(Session["removed"] == true)
{
     lblRekeningMakenInfo.Text = "The value is removed!";
     Session["removed"] = null;
}
```

When removing you should set the session:

```
Session["removed"] = true;
```